# Using checkToken() to secure form posts

Tags: php, joomla-api, security, joomla-framework-1.x, security-token

I am building a web app using the [Jooma Framework](https://github.com/joomla-framework) and the [Framework App](https://github.com/dbhurley/framework-app) as a template. I have getFormToken() working as described in [this post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/implement-csrf-anti-spoofing-using-the-joomla-framework) and am now submitting the token with my form but I cannot get checkToken() working. This is the code I have so far to setup the session and get the token:

```
$session = Session::getInstance('none', $options);
$session->initialise($this->app->input);
$session->start();
$this->app->setSession($session);
$token = $this->app->getFormToken();
```

The problem in that on every page load, $token is a new value causing checkToken() to fail and exit the app. I can see that the session.token is correctly set in my $_SESSION variable when the next page starts loading but when I called getInstance to get the session, the first thing it does is call session_unset() and session_destroy() which clears session.token.

So how can I get access to the session without clearing it every time? Is there another way to check the form token that was created on a previous page load?

Many thanks,

Comment: Is it possible that your app is forcing a new session on each page load? (and thus overwriting the previous session?)

Comment: Yes, this could be happening. However, when I look session_id(), this doesn't change between page loads.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the code

```
$session = Session::getInstance('none', $options);
```

creates a new instance.

But what you need is to get the session that is active, try to use

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
```

I have not tried out but I know. Please let me know the results.

Thanks